# Check if any object has given value for specific field

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I need to check if any object has a given value for a specific field.

In this example I want to check all `value` for `find me` - which is true

```
const example = [
  {
    text: 'something',
    value: 'some value'
  },
  {
    text: 'anything',
    value: 'find me'
  }
]
```

The same search (check all `value` fields for `find me` value) should be false in this example:

```
const example = [
  {
    text: 'something',
    value: 'some value'
  },
  {
    text: 'anything',
    value: 'another value'
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
const hasField = example.some(obj => obj.value === 'find me');
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method.

```
example.some(obj => obj.value === 'find me');
```

Here is the example code:

```js
var example1 = [{
    text: 'something',
    value: 'some value'
}, {
    text: 'anything',
    value: 'another value'
}]

var example2 = [{
    text: 'something',
    value: 'some value'
}, {
    text: 'anything',
    value: 'find me'
}]

console.log(example1.some(obj=>obj.value === 'find me'));
// false
console.log(example2.some(obj=>obj.value === 'find me'));
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic search function using `.some()` and Object Destructuring:

```js
const example1 = [{text: 'something',value: 'some value'},{text: 'anything',value: 'find me'}];
const example2 = [{text: 'something',value: 'some value'},{text: 'anything',value: 'another value'}];

let locator = (arr, str) => arr.some(({value}) => value == str);

console.log(locator(example1, 'find me'));
console.log(locator(example2, 'find me'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple method using `Array.filter()`:

```
function getObjectsWithMatchedValue(array, searchValue) {
  // Find Object(s) in array where Object.value === searchValue
  return array.filter((item) => {
    return item.value === searchValue;
  });
}

const example1 = [
  {
    text: 'something',
    value: 'some value'
  },
  {
    text: 'anything',
    value: 'find me'
  }
];

const example2 = [
  {
    text: 'something',
    value: 'some value'
  },
  {
    text: 'anything',
    value: 'another value'
  }
];

getObjectsWithMatchedValue(example1, 'find me');
/*
  expected return:
  [
    {
      text: 'anything',
      value: 'find me'
    }
  ]
*/


getObjectsWithMatchedValue(example2, 'find me');
/*
  expected return:
  []
*/
```

**Note:** *This will return all matching objects from the array, so you could wrap it to check the length and return false if it is 0.*